# How to properly use intptr to return char* value from c++ DLL to Vb.net

Tags: c++, vb.net, visual-c++, char, marshalling

I have been able to achieve a program that imports a C++ DLL function and uses it correctly to get the required calculated values. I'm returning the char* values to VB.net using an **intptr** pointer.

It works fine, however, I cant seem to rest or clear the memory space where the result from the function is stored. When i call the function the first time it gives me the right answers, when it is called the second time, it gives me both the first and the second answers.

Here are relevant parts of my code:
CPM.cpp - The function that calculated the return variables in the cpp file

```
char* CPMfn(char* sdatabase, int project_num)
{
/* Retrieve data from database and calculate CPM for the selected project number*/  

char* testvector = getCPM(sdatabase, project_num);
return testvector;
}
```

CPM.h - the header file for exporting the function

```
#pragma once
#ifdef CPM_EXPORTS
#define CPM_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CPM_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
extern "C" CPM_API char* CPMfn(char*, int);
```

VB.net code to import the DLL, declare the function and use it

```vb
'' Import C++ CPM Calculation function from CPM DLL
<DllImport("CPM.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Private Shared Function CPMfn(ByVal dbstring As Char(), ByVal task As Int32) As System.IntPtr
End Function

'' Get CPM results from DLL function with database location string and selected project number
CPMresults = CPMfn(DBString, Val(Project_IDTextBox.Text))
CPMvalues = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(CPMresults)
If CPMvalues.Length() = 0 Then
    MsgBox("No tasks for seleccted project")
Else
    MsgBox(CPMvalues)           ' Show CPM values
End If
```

As I run it consecutively the string just keeps getting longer i.e. 4th function call would return the values for project 1, 2, 3 and 4.
I've checked online for the past few hours trying to figure out how to return char* from C++ DLLs and then how to clear the intptr.
I just haven't had any luck with the solutions suggested. I would really really appreciate some help.
Thank you!

Comment: Instead of marshalling it yourself, why not let the framework do it for you? I'm not sure how it works as a return type, but I believe `char*` can be mapped to a `StringBuilder` (`const char*` is mapped to `String`). I don't think that changing it will solve your actual issue though (but I could be wrong), perhaps `getCPM` reuses the same char array? Do you have some sort of documentation for this method?

Comment: The `char*` can be mapped to `string` instead of `StringBuilder`, if it is allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc()` and marshaled as an `UnmanagedType.LPStr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the following MSDN documentation:

[Default Marshaling Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior)

> **The interop marshaler always attempts to free memory allocated by unmanaged code**. This behavior complies with COM memory management rules, but differs from the rules that govern native C++.
>
> Confusion can arise if you anticipate native C++ behavior (no memory freeing) when using platform invoke, which automatically frees memory for pointers. For example, calling the following unmanaged method from a C++ DLL does not automatically free any memory.
>
> Unmanaged signature
>
> ```
> BSTR MethodOne (BSTR b) {  
>      return b;  
> }
> ```
>
> However, if you define the method as a platform invoke prototype, replace each `BSTR` type with a `String` type, and call `MethodOne`, the common language runtime attempts to free `b` twice. You can change the marshaling behavior by using `IntPtr` types rather than `String` types.
>
> **The runtime always uses the `CoTaskMemFree` method to free memory**. If the memory you are working with was not allocated with the `CoTaskMemAlloc` method, you must use an `IntPtr` and free the memory manually using the appropriate method. Similarly, you can avoid automatic memory freeing in situations where memory should never be freed, such as when using the `GetCommandLine` function from `Kernel32.dll`, which returns a pointer to kernel memory. For details on manually freeing memory, see the [Buffers Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e30d36e8-d7c4-4936-916a-8fdbe4d9ffd5(v=vs.100)).

So, the DLL needs to dynamically allocate a new `char*` string each time it returns, and the VB code needs to be told how to free that string properly.  There are a few ways to handle this:

- have the DLL return a `char*` (or `wchar_t*`) string that is allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc()`, and then change the PInvoke to take the return value as a `string` marshaled as an `UnmanagedType.LPStr` (or `UnmanagedType.LPWStr`).  The .NET runtime will then free the memory for you using `CoTaskMemFree()`.
- change the DLL to return a COM `BSTR` string that is allocated with `SysAllocString()`, and then change the PInvoke to take the return value as a `string` marshaled as an `UnmanagedType.BStr`.  The .NET runtime will then free the memory for you using `SysFreeString()`.
- if you want to have the DLL return a raw `char*` (or `wchar_t*`) string and have PInvoke treat it as an `IntPtr` (because it is not allocated using `CoTaskMemAlloc()` to `SysAllocString()`), then the .NET runtime will have no way of knowing how the string was allocated and so cannot free the memory automatically.  So either:

  - the `IntPtr` will have to be passed back to the DLL when done being used, since only the DLL will know how the memory was allocated, so only the DLL will be able to free it properly.
  - have the DLL allocate the `char*` (or `wchar_t*`) string using `LocalAlloc()`, and then the .NET code can use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()` (or `Marshal.PtrToStringUni()`) to get a `string` from the `IntPtr`, and then pass the `IntPtr` to `Marshal.FreeHGlobal()` when done using it.

See the following article for more details (it is written for C#, but you can adapt it for VB.NET):

[Returning Strings from a C++ API to C#](https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/returning-strings-from-a-c-api/)

Comment: I didn't know that .NET also takes care of cleaning up the unmanaged memory like that! Until know I haven't really known what `UnmanagedType.LPStr` was actually used for, and the docs's description _"A pointer to a null-terminated array of ANSI characters."_ isn't very informational. Thanks for teaching me today's pearl of wisdom!

Comment: Hi Remy, thank you so much for the explanation and the included links. Really helped me understand a bit better.

Comment: i ran into some issues that I couldn't figure out a solution to. I posted my code below

Comment: @SayeedaO that should have been added as an edit to your question, not posted as an answer.

Comment: oh thank you, wasn't sure how to show the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Remy Lebeau. I've tried implementing the CoTaskMemAlloc() method and it works!. My code is as follows:

In the **cpp** file i've edited the return value to be allocated using the CoTaskMemAlloc()

```
char* CPMfn(char* sdatabase, int project_num)
{
/* Retrieve data from database and calculate CPM for the selected project number*/
char* CPMvector = getCPM(sdatabase, project_num);

/* Store results in specially allocated memory space that can easily be deallocated when this DLL is called*/
ULONG ulSize = strlen(CPMvector) + sizeof(char);
char* ReturnValue = NULL;

ReturnValue = (char*)::CoTaskMemAlloc(ulSize);
// Copy the contents of CPMvector
// to the memory pointed to by ReturnValue.
int charlen = strlen(CPMvector);
strcpy_s(ReturnValue, charlen + 1, CPMvector);
// Return
return ReturnValue;
}
```

In the **VB.net** file I've written the Dllimport and Marshalling code as follows:

```vb
'' Import C++ CPM Calculation function from CPM DLL
<DllImport("CPM.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
Private Shared Function CPMfn(ByVal dbstring As String, ByVal task As Int32) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> String
End Function  

'' Get CPM results from DLL function
 Dim teststring As String = CPMfn(cDBString, Val(Project_IDTextBox.Text))
```

**Alternatively** I've also tried freeing up the allocated memory manually using the `GlobalAlloc()` and `Marshal.FreeHGlobal()` functions but i'm getting the same results (i.e. first call = 1,2,3\n, second call = 1,2,3\n,4,5,6\n instead of just 4,5,6\n).
Here's my code with the `GlobalAlloc()` method:

In .cpp file

```
ReturnValue = (char*)::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, ulSize);
strcpy_s(ReturnValue, strlen(CPMvector) + 1, CPMvector);
```

And in VB.net file

```vb
<DllImport("CPM.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Private Shared Function CPMfn(ByVal dbstring As Char(), ByVal task As Int32) As System.IntPtr
End Function    

Dim CPMresults As IntPtr = CPMfn(cDBString, Val(Project_IDTextBox.Text))
Dim CPMvalues As String = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(CPMresults)
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(CPMresults)
CPMresults = IntPtr.Zero
```

Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: Your C++ code is wrong. Specifically, if `charlen` is 0, you leak the memory you allocate, and return a pointer to memory that was not allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc()`. Just get rid of the check for 0 and call `strcpy_s` unconditionally (or, at least replace `ReturnValue = ""` with `*ReturnValue = '\0'` instead) . Also, do you need to free the memory that `getCPM()` returns?

Comment: Also, in the VB code, `ByVal dbstring As Char()` should be `ByVal dbstring As String`

Comment: @RemyLebeau : Shouldn't `char*` as a parameter be declared as `StringBuilder`? (or at the least be marshalled as `UnmanagedType.LPStr`?)

Comment: ohhh thank you so much. I've edited the code  and called the `strcopy_s` unconditionally. And also changed the dbstring character type to `String`. It works fine now, but unfortunately still does the same thing and aggregates the results each time the function is called with the results from previous calls..

Comment: Regarding the `getCPM` return, am I right to assume the variable would be destroyed/deallocated at the end of the `CPMfn` function?

Comment: @VisualVincent `StringBuilder` CAN be used, but `String` will work just as well, too. Both types can be marshaled to unmanaged code as a null-terminated string (in fact, that is the ONLY marshaling option that is supported for `StringBuilder`, whereas `String` can be marshaled as either a NTS or a `BSTR`).

Comment: @SayeedaO `getCPM()` returns a `char*` pointer. What does it actually point to? Dynamically allocated memory, or static memory? Either way, that memory will NOT be deallocated automatically when `CPMfn()` exits. If it is dynamic, you must deallocate it yourself. In any case, your aggregating issue really sounds like a flaw in `getCPM()` itself, not in your VB code (you can verify that by debugging `CPMfn()`, such as displaying `testvector` in a popup messagebox). What does the code for `getCPM()` look like? How does it get memory for its return value, and populate that memory with data?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for all the time you've invested. About your question, i'm just getting familiar with the concept of pointers and memory allocation with c++. So i hope i answer correctly. the `getCPM()` function returns as follows: `char* CPMValues = new char[CPMString.length() + 1];` `strcpy_s(CPMValues, CPMString.length() + 1, CPMString.c_str());`
`return CPMValues;` Those are the last lines of the code block for `getCPM()` So would i have to deallocate it within the `CPMfn` function?

Comment: @SayeedaO yes, `CPMfn()` must call `delete[] testvestors;` before exiting, otherwise the memory will be leaked.  Why is `getCPM()` returning a `char*` at all, and not simply returning `CPMString` as-is instead? In any case, how is `CPMString` populated? That is the character data being passed back to the VB code, so did you check to make sure that `CPMString` is not accumulating characters over time? Maybe there is another function call you are missing to clear `CPMString` after you retrieve it?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you sooo much! you're such a blessing. You were completely right. i wasn't clearing the matrices that were populating `CPMString` so the values were just aggregating. When I had tested it as a standalone C++ program it worked fine because i was building and compiling with each call to the function. But hadn't tested it while recalling the function multiple times at runtime. I added a `clear()` function for the matrices and that solved the problem! Thank you!!!